# Python - AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: random, python-3.x, attributeerror

As part of a python course I am doing one of the tasks is to generate a random number between 1 and 10 100,000 times and count how many times each number occurs. Here is the code I have written for this task:

```
    import random

    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four = 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    seven = 0
    eight = 0
    nine = 0
    ten = 0
    count = 0

    while count < 100000:
        random = random.randint(1, 10)

        if random == 1:
            one += 1
        elif random == 2:
            two += 1
        elif random == 3:
            three += 1
        elif random == 4:
            four += 1
        elif random == 5:
            five += 1
        elif random == 6:
            six += 1
        elif random == 7:
            seven += 1
        elif random == 8:
            eight += 1
        elif random == 9:
            nine += 1
        else:
            ten += 1

    count += 1

    print("1 occured " + str(one) + " times")
    print("2 occured " + str(two) + " times")
    print("3 occured " + str(three) + " times")
    print("4 occured " + str(four) + " times")
    print("5 occured " + str(five) + " times")
    print("6 occured " + str(six) + " times")
    print("7 occured " + str(seven) + " times")
    print("8 occured " + str(eight) + " times")
    print("9 occured " + str(nine) + " times")
    print("10 occured " + str(ten) + " times")
```

However I get an AttributeError saying:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "J:/Python/Extension Task - Random Numbers.py", line 19, in <module>
        random = random.randint(1, 10)
    AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'randint'
```

I've tried changing the title so that it doesn't include the word random and it still doesn't work, I've spent much longer than is healthy looking for solution to no avail.

Answer (score 8):

You have named one of your variables `random`, which is shadowing the name of the module you're trying to use:

```
random = random.randint(1, 10)
```

After this line, `random` is your random number, not the `random` module.  Use a different name for this variable!

Comment: Thank you I just realised that and was coming on to apologise for my ignorance and stupidity :P

Comment: I had the same error due to calling my file random.py